# Getting this warning " Control may reach end of non-void function "

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, adt

I keep getting this error "Control may reach end of non-void function". Can anyone help me get through?  I am stuck here. Thank you.

```
bool Vector_double::erase(int ind1, int ind2){
    if(ind1 >= count || ind2 >= count || ind1 >= ind2){
       if(ind1 == ind2){
          erase(ind1);
          return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    else{
       double *narr = new double[count - ind2 - 1];
       for(int i = ind2 + 1; i < count; ++i){
          narr[i - ind2 - 1] = arr[i];
       }
       for(int i = ind1; i < ind1 + count - ind2 - 1;++i){
          arr[i] = narr[i - ind1];
       }
       count = count - (ind2 - ind1) - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your function return on the else part?

Comment: Where does it release the allocated array in the second part? BTW: I'd remove the `else` after a `return` or at least use it consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Your function promises to return something (`bool`). However, the code contains paths that don't return anything. In order to fix this bug, start by documenting (in plain English) what the returned value is supposed to express. Then, adjust your code.